# $ \mathbb{A}^{1}_{k}\backslash \lbrace a_{1},\dots,a_{l} \rbrace \cong \mathbb{A}^{1}_{k}\backslash \lbrace b_{1},\dots,b_{m} \rbrace. $ Is $ l = m?$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

By assumption, the points $ a_{1},\dots,a_{l} $ are distinct from $ b_{1},\dots,b_{m}. $

We know that for an affine variety $ V $ and for $ f \in k[V], $ we have the quasi-affine variety $$ V_{f} = V \backslash V(f) = \lbrace P \in V\;|\;f(P) \neq 0 \rbrace, $$ and furthermore $ V_{f} $ is isomorphic to $ \operatorname{Spec}k[V]_{f}. $

I'm not sure about the following:

So if $$ f:\mathbb{A}^{1}_{k}\backslash \lbrace a_{1},\dots,a_{l} \rbrace \longrightarrow  \mathbb{A}^{1}_{k}\backslash \lbrace b_{1},\dots,b_{m} \rbrace, $$ is an isomorphism, then we have some resulting isomorphism $$ f^{*}: k[x]_{\prod_{i=1}^{l}(x-a_{i})} \longrightarrow k[x]_{\prod_{i=1}^{m}(x-b_{i})}.    $$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: This has too many gaps for me to want to post it as an answer, but something like this should work: a $k$-vector space basis of the source ring would be $(x-a_1)^{-1}, (x-a_2)^{-1},...,(x-a_l)^{-1}, 1, x, x^2,...$, while a basis of the target ring is $(x-b_1)^{-1}, (x-b_2)^{-1},...,(x-b_m)^{-1}, 1, x, x^2,...$. If you can show that the image of ${1,x,x^2,...}$ has the same span as $1,x,x^2,...$ in the target, then there must be an isomorphism from the $k$-span of the negative degree elements on the left to the span of the negative degree elements on the right. By linear algebra, $l=m$....

Comment: ...As far as showing the claim about the elements of nonnegative degree, perhaps use that they are precisely those which extend to regular functions on the whole of $\mathbb A^1$?

Comment: @TabesBridges: How do you write $(x-a_{1})^{-2}$ in that first basis?

Comment: Oy, good point, that's not a basis at all...I may be over complicating things. Maybe just observe that on each side of the ring map, you have a finite generating set, and the elements that extend to the affine line must be preserved by $f^*$.

Comment: @TabesBridges I'm not really sure what you mean by "the elements that extend to the affine line"

Comment: @ConfusedStudent We have a natural inclusion map $i:\mathbb A^1\setminus \left\{a_1,...,a_l\right\} \to \mathbb A^1$ hence a homomorphism $i^*$ from $k[x]$ to the localization. By "extends to the affine line" I mean "is in the image of $i^*$." In other words, I'm talking about functions on the punctured line which arise as the restriction of a function on the whole line. A simple example is that $f(x) = 1/x$ is a function on $\mathbb A^1 \setminus \left\{0\right\}$ which doesn't extend.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field, let $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{K}}$ be the affine line over $\mathbb{K}$; in this case, the Zariski topology of $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{K}}$ is the cofinite topology, so any bijective and continuous function $f:\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{K}}\to\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{K}}$ is an homeomorphism.

Restricted $f$ to $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{K}}\setminus\{a_1,\dots,a_m\}$, one has that its image via $f$ is the (open) set $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{K}}\setminus\{b_1,\dots,b_m\}$.

In particular, this reasoning holds for any regular isomorphism $g:\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{K}}\setminus\{a_1,\dots,a_l\}\to\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{K}}\setminus\{b_1,\dots,b_m\}$, because $g$ is also an homeomorphism and then $l=m$!

Comment: Surely $ \mathbb{A}^{1}_{k}\backslash \lbrace a_{1},\dots,a_{l} \rbrace $ and $ \mathbb{A}^{1}_{k}\backslash \lbrace b_{1},\dots,b_{m} \rbrace $ are both open sets. No? Also, I'm not entirely sure why the fact that $ g $ is an isomophism implies that $ l=m. $ It seems intuitively true though.

Comment: I edited the answer.